# JMeter save response to file with custom extension

Tags: jmeter

I try to save response of a `HTTP Request` with custom file extension. ContentType is `application/octet-stream` and saved file ends with `_1.octet-stream` by default. I use `Save Responses to a file` listener to save file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [Save responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener as a child of the request which output you would like to save
2. Configure it like:

   [image]

   Replace `myfile.txt` with your desired filename/extension
3. That's it, assuming the above configuration JMeter will store the file under the given name

Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information with regards to simulating file downloads in JMeter tests